# Internal Error when updating Odoo website route from public to user

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to restrict all blogs access for only authenticated users, because all blog posts are public by default, I am using the following class to override the blog routes (ex. /blog/myblogs-2):

```
class RestrictWebBLog(WebsiteBlog):
    @http.route(auth='user')
    def blogs(self):
        return super(RestrictWebBLog, self).blogs()

    @http.route(auth='user')
    def blog_post(self):
        return super(RestrictWebBLog, self).blog_post()

    @http.route(auth='user')
    def blog(self):
        return super(RestrictWebBLog, self).blog()
```

It seems to work, because login is required when trying to access any blog, but after entering credentials, the following error appears:

Error Message:

```
blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blog'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 203, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 833, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 344, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 939, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
TypeError: blog() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blog'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to write the arguments in the function same as original function.

For example the function `blogs()`, have more arguments in original function , like

```
def blogs(self, page=1, **post):
```

So try to define with all arguments as in the original function.

Comment: You are correct, after adding the arguments worked! Thank you!